# Why can't I set NODE_ENV to undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to implement a test where my code works correctly in different Node.js environments, by changing and testing the value of variable `NODE_ENV`.

What I'm stuck with, is trying to understand why the following code:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = undefined;

var test = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'empty';

console.log(test);
```

outputs `undefined` instead of `empty`.

Is that some JavaScript or Node.js feature that I'm missing here?

Tested under Node.js versions: 0.10.47, 4.6.1 and 6.9.1

---

#### update

As a work-around for this specific case I had to do the following:

```
delete process.env.NODE_ENV; // now it is undefined
```

Comment: That's weird. I would certainly expect it to output `empty`. It's not a consequence of using strict mode is it?

Comment: @Carcigenicate my sentiment exactly, it is weird, hence the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's doing that for me with 6.2.2.

Comment: It's **very** subtle. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It is the smallest mosquito that annoys most ;)

Comment: All values are properties, but not all properties are values. Some are read-only, and some even do weird things if you try to assign to them (think about what happens when you assign to `window.location` in a browser).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It's **very** subtle: According to [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env):

> Assigning a property on process.env will implicitly convert the value to a string.

So you're getting back `"undefined"` from `process.env.NODE_ENV`, not `undefined`. `"undefined"` is truthy, so `"undefined" || "empty"` is `"undefined"`.

You can see that if you modify your script a bit:

```
'use strict';

process.env.NODE_ENV = undefined;

console.log("process.env.NODE_ENV", typeof process.env.NODE_ENV, process.env.NODE_ENV);
var test = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'empty';

console.log("test", typeof test, test);
console.log("process.env.NODE_ENV", typeof process.env.NODE_ENV, process.env.NODE_ENV);
```

...which outputs:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV string undefined
test string undefined
process.env.NODE_ENV string undefined
```

Comment: Oh of course, it wasn't `undefined`, it was `"undefined"`. Good going JavaScript...

Comment: This particular conversion is technically _necessary_, because the system-level environment variable vector can only contain string values. A language designed today would probably require an explicit conversion, but JS is generally implicit-conversion-happy, so this behavior is "what you would expect".

Comment: @zwol: Oh, I don't at all know that "a language designed today" would necessarily be strongly-typed. There are ebbs and flows, though, it's true.

Comment: @JamEngulfer: You find the difference between `1` and `"1"` ambiguous? Because that's exactly the difference between `undefined` and `"undefined"`.

Comment: Not sure why anyone would want to manipulate at runtime after the process has started (I'd stay away from it), but as a note you can clear it by calling 'delete process.env.NODE_ENV'

Comment: @JamEngulfer this doesn't seem to be a JavaScript issue at all, more so one with Node.js.

Comment: You might want to add that the proper solution for the OPs problem (to get the result `'empty'`) would be not to `delete` the property, but rather to set it to the empty string `""` instead of `undefined`.

Comment: @Bergi When environment variable `NODE_ENV` is not defined at all, you are getting `undefined`, so really, in your tests you would want to be able to test when it is `undefined`, and not just an empty string. That's why I was trying to set it to `undefined` in the first place.

Comment: @vitaly-t Ah, I see. And actually even the docs recommend to "*Use `delete` to delete a property from `process.env`.*"

Answer (score 0):

The workaround to make envs to undefined is to set all the envs to undefined as below:

```
process.env = {}
```

or as vitaly-t said, delete this env:

```
delete process.env.NODE_ENV
```